# Javascript: how to sort an array for a normal distribution chart?

Tags: javascript, arrays, charts, normal-distribution

I have to sort an array for a normal distribution chart, so its values must be sorted from the minimum value to the maximum value and then back to minimum, creating a curve.

Example:

Array:

```
[200, 300, 0, 100, 400]
```

How it must be sorted:

```
[0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 300, 200, 100, 0]
```

Any ideas of how to do this in Javascript?

Comment: What have you tried to solve the problem?

Comment: @AlbertiBuonarroti yes, I did. I got to where I sort the array and create the chart, but  I couldn't reverse the array when it gets to the maximum.

Comment: Could you share your code so we can build upon your solution?

Comment: Numerous ways to do this....show what you have tried. Objective here is to help fix your code not to write all the code for you

Comment: Sort it, then append a reversed copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this using [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), [`reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) and [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```js
const array = [200, 300, 0, 100, 400]
const newArray = [...array.sort((a,b) => a - b), ...array.reverse().slice(1)]

console.log(newArray)
```

- `array.sort((a,b) => a - b)` sorts the array
- `array.reverse()` reverses the sorted array
- `slice(1)` to remove the duplicate max value from the reversed array

**Note**: This just generates a normal distribution array from the existing array by creating duplicate values as you requested. But if you want to just convert an array to normal distribution, *without* adding any elements, then take a look at [@Nina's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54845357/3082296).

Comment: Thank you, @adiga. I marked your answer as accepted, due to your explanation. I couldn't reverse the array without duplicating the value before your answer.

Answer (score 6):

For a distribution of elements of a (descending) sorted array, you could use a shuffe sort of the keys and map the value to the array.

```js
var data = [200, 300, 0, 100, 200, 300, 0, 100, 400].sort((a, b) => b - a),
    result = Array
        .from(data.keys())
        .sort((a, b) => b % 2 - a % 2 || (a % 2 ? b - a : a - b))
        .map(i => data[i]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```